# smallest known superset of a set expression with unknown sets

Tags: algorithms

I have an expression of set unions and intersections, but one or more sets are unknown.
An easy example (X is the unknown set):
$S = (A \cap X) \cup B$.
I am searching for an algorithm to give me the smallest **known** superset of S given the expression above.
In this case the answer would be $A \cup B$.
More examples: (U is the "set of everything")
$A \cup X$ -> U
$A \cap X$ -> A
$(A \cap X)^C$ -> U
$((A \cap X) \cup B)^C$ -> $B^C$

Apologies if this is rather a question for stackoverflow, in that case let me know.

Comment: given S(X), is the answer S(X = {}) U S(X = U)? i assume that the answer resides at one of both extrema of possible X, either empty set or U.

Comment: actually i don't think this is true, need to find a counter-example